# Error on handling mouse events on cocoa

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, mouseevent, nsevent

I've got a custom `ViewController`, a custom `WindowController` and a custom `View`. The `ViewController` is connected to the `WindowController` and the `View` is connected to the `ViewController`.

In my `ViewController` I have the following code for the mouse events:

```
override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) { 
     //code
}

override func mouseUp(with event: NSEvent) {
     //code
}
```

On launching this, I'm getting the following error message and furthermore on debugging these methods are not even entered:

```
2018-03-08 11:27:11.594158+0100 MyProject[2697:83761] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent touchesMatchingPhase:inView:], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1504.83.101/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:4654
2018-03-08 11:27:11.594574+0100 MyProject[2697:83761] [General] Invalid message sent to event "NSEvent: type=LMouseDown loc=(701.219,422.156) time=8788.4 flags=0 win=0x6080001e0200 winNum=1255 ctxt=0x0 evNum=1071 click=1 buttonNumber=0 pressure=1 deviceID:0x300000014400000 subtype=NSEventSubtypeTouch"
2018-03-08 11:27:11.599387+0100 MyProject[2697:83761] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b59d2cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffa03b548d objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b5a2042 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8cfeabe0 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff89327573 -[NSEvent touchesMatchingPhase:inView:] + 205
    5   MyProject                           0x0000000100013c0b _T015MyProject18MyViewControllerC9mouseDownySo7NSEventC4with_tF + 139
    6   MyProject                           0x0000000100014bbc _T015MyProject18MyViewControllerC9mouseDownySo7NSEventC4with_tFTo + 60
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff891897a9 forwardMethod + 133
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff891897a9 forwardMethod + 133
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff8990424f -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 6341
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff89900a6c -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 1942
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff898fff0a -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 541
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff89784681 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 1145
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff88fff427 -[NSApplication run] + 1002
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff88fc9e0e NSApplicationMain + 1237
    15  MyProject                           0x0000000100023add main + 13
    16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fffa0c9b235 start + 1
)
```

I've already tried the following things:

1. Register these both methods in the WindowController and just write in each:

   let vc = self.nextResponder as! MyViewController
        vc.mouseUp // or vc.mouseDown

--> still getting the above error

2. Register these both methods in the `viewDidLoad() / windowDidLoad()` by writing the following Code:

   ```
   NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .leftMouseDown){
       self.mouseDown(with: $0)
       return $0 
   }


   NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .leftMouseUp){
       self.mouseUp(with: $0)
       return $0
   }
   ```

--> still getting the above error

**Question:** How can I make these both methods work in my ViewController?

**Important Note:** Please consider that I am using `Swift 4.0.2` and Xcode `9.1 Build 9B55`

Comment: Do you call `touches(matching:in:)` in `mouseDown(with:)`?

Comment: The program does not even jump into mouseDown(with:), so won't it be useless anyway?

Comment: Yes, stupid question. I have to read better. It says `MyViewController` instead of `ViewController`. Do you have a class `MyViewController` in `MyProject`?

Comment: Yes, sir. This is the custom ViewController class from MyProject. I need these mouse-handling methods in the ViewController-class as the references which I need to work with are there ...

Comment: The backtrace says `touches(matching:in:)` is called from `mouseDown(with:)` of `MyViewController`.

Comment: yes you were right, my problem was the 'touches(matching:in:)'. It has trhrown the error. It is not a touch event, but a mousevent, that's why the errormessage ... You can write this as answer, then I will mark it ... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error:

```
Assertion failure in -[NSEvent touchesMatchingPhase:inView:]
Invalid message sent to event "NSEvent: type=LMouseDown
```

`touches(matching:in:)` is called from `mouseDown(with:)`. The documentation of `touches(matching:in:)` says:

> This method is only valid for gesture events (gesture, magnify, swipe, rotate, etc.).